# @Aspect in spring

Tags: java, spring, aop

I try use `@Aspect` in spring application. I would like before executing method `getName()`, execute method `getNameAdvice()`. It helps me understand `@Aspect` in spring,  but I can't understand, why it doesn't work. Method `getNameAdvice()` just doesn't execute. Intelij see that method `getNameAdvice()`  for method `getName()`. It is very weird.

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        Employee employee = applicationContext.getBean(Employee.class);
        System.out.println(employee.getName());
    }

}
```

```java
package com.example.demo;


public class Employee {
    String name;
    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean(name ="employee")
    public Employee employee(){
        return new Employee("Jan");
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class EmployeeAspect {

    @Before("execution(public String getName())")
    public void getNameAdvice(){
        System.out.println("Executing Advice on getName()");
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure, but it's possible you have to make sure aop knows which method of which class it's applied on.

Comment: And it should because? THe aspect isn't even scanned or created (no aspect in use for that matter) nor does your aspect contain a proper expression afaik.

Comment: Yes, you're right, missing @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.demo") in AppConfig class. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You coded a wrong pointcut expression。Spring does not know what class or witch package to find your [public String getName()] method.
I googled a example you can reference。

> @Before("execution(public * com.wener.example.aop.execution.ExecutionService.add(..))")

Comment: This answer is wrong. The OP's poinctut loks fine to me. It will apply to all methods matching the name, return type and modifiers, without regard to the class the methods belong to. This is valid AspectJ syntax.